# System.argumentException while inserting xml node into document

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xpath

I am trying to insert an xml node into another node in an xml document however I am continuously getting a `"system.ArgumentException"` whenever I test it. I have tried several ways of inserting the node but cannot work out how to fix it.

here's the code:

```
Dim content As String = "<name>" + songName + "</name><artist>" + songArtist + "</artist><album>" +   songAlbum + "</album>"
            Dim doc As New XmlDocument
            doc.Load(getPath())
            Dim i As XmlNode = doc.CreateElement("song")
            i.InnerXml = content

            Try
                list.AppendChild(i)
            Catch

            End Try

            doc.Save(getPath())
            Return True
        End If

    End If
```

I know from stepping and using the try catch statement that the error is "The node to be inserted is from a different document context." and it occurs at the "list.AppendChild(I)" line in the code.

could anyone offer any suggestions to fix this error please?

**EDIT**

I tried using doc.AppendChild() instead of list.AppendChild() and got an error message (shown in the comments).

looking back at a previous method where I inserted another node into my document I used "root.AppendChild()" so I am pretty sure list is the right variable to use

Comment: Why `list.AppendChild(i)` instead of `doc.AppendChild(i)`?

Comment: wow I never noticed that! i'll try and change that

Comment: didn't work, using doc.AppendChild(I) I get an error "InvalidOperationException" with a message "doc.appendChild(I) doesn't work, now I get an "InvalidOperationException" with a message: "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node"

Comment: Show how you declare variable `list`. And try `doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(i)`, that will fix the later exception...

Answer (score 0):

The issue as I understand it, is that you need to import your document first, then append to it. Please see a sample below.

http://www.dailyfreecode.com/forum/node-inserted-different-document-40.aspx